# Export a specific sheet from Tableau using tabcmd

Tags: tableau-api

I am using tabcmd to export some sheets to csv in tabcmd. The issue i am having is my view contains 3 sheets and i can only get one.

I have 3 sheets

```
1)A
2)B
3)C
```

I want to export the data for sheet C

Here is the command I use

```
tabcmd export "Q1Sales/Sales_Report" --csv -f "Weekly-Report.csv"
```

This command always returns sheet A or the first sheet alphabetically. Is there a way around this or any suggestions of a better method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your argument is not in proper format (missing the --cvs). Per the docs, it should be:

```
tabcmd export "Q1Sales/Sales_Report" --csv -f "Weekly-Report.csv"
```

See link for more details. 
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd_cmd.htm#id7cb8d032-a4ff-43da-9990-15bdfe64bcd0

Comment: thanks Bernardo, edited the post for clarity. Any way to get the other two or all sheets that you know of?

Comment: I think you'd need a separate tabcmd line for each sheet. You can make a batch file and run that. https://www.interworks.com/blog/ktreadwell/2012/09/07/automating-dashboard-delivery-using-tabcmd

Comment: It still will always return the same sheet

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply:

```
tabcmd export "Q1Sales/C" --csv -f "Weekly-Report.csv"
```

If you use tableau server please be sure that the sheet is visible there.